# 301 redirects with multiple domains

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm currently running a website which has a 'multi store' feature, which essentially means that the single site handles multiple domains. In this instance, I have `domain-a.com` and `domain-b.com` both pointing at the one store. Currently, they have a blog set up at `domain-a.com/blog`, which can be accessed from both sites.

Recently, we wanted to set up a separate blog for each domain, so we moved the blog from `domain-a.com/blog` to `blog.domain-a.com`, and set up a 301 redirect in the htaccess file to forward traffic from `domain-a.com/blog` to the new location. The problem is, this also redirects traffic coming in on `domain-b.com/blog` to `blog.domain-a.com`. Using only the .htaccess, is there away to make `domain-a.com/blog` redirect to `blog.domain-a.com` and `domain-b.com/blog` redirect to a totally different location, say `domain-b.com/newBlog`?

EDIT: End of last paragraph has been reworded for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These rules will do the job:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blog$ http://blog.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

1. Place it in **.htaccess** in website root folder. If placed elsewhere then some small rule tweaking is required.
2. These rules will work for the domain names you have provided (e.g. `domain-x.com` => `blog.domain-x.com`). If domain name is different (e.g. `www.domain-x.com`) then in order to redirect to `blog.domain-x.com` these rules have to be changed.

---

**UPDATE:**
Based on updated requirements:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# rule for domain-A.com/blog
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =domain-a.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog(/?|/(.*))$ http://blog.domain-a.com/$2 [NC,R=301,L]

# rule for domain-B.com/blog
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =domain-b.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog(/?|/(.*))$ http://domain-b.com/newBlog/$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: They already have rules to redirect from `domain-a.com/blog`  to `blog.domain-a.com`.

Comment: @AlexD Based on the description it is my understanding that they both get redirected to `blog.domain-a.com` regardless of the original URL and now Geoff wants to redirect to a `blog` subdomain but keep domain name part unchanged. This rule does exactly that. If he needs something else (e.g. redirecting to a completely different places: `domain-a.com/blog` => `blog.domain-a.com` while `domain-b.com/blog` => `somewhere-else.example.com`) then these rules would not work and question needs to be altered to clarify this moment.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay enough attention and missed using HTTP_HOST in your rules. Thanks for thorough explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, `domain-a.com/blog` needs to go to `blog.domain-a.com`, but `domain-b.com/blog` needs to go to a different location, say `domain-b.com/newblog` for example. I'll amend the question now to clarify this

Comment: @Geoff Sure, I will update my answer when I see your exact requirements.

Comment: My exact requirements would be as follows: `domain-a.com/blog` redirects to `blog.domain-a.com` and `domain-b.com/blog` redirects to `domain-b.com/newblog`

Comment: @Geoff Please check my updated answer.

Comment: That is fantastic, just what I was after. Thanks for your help.